# Can we authenticate user by username as well as email from username field in django?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-views

I am using Django built-in authentication. A user can be login by username and password from django login form. But I want the user to be able to login with email id and password too.

The login form has only  **username** field. Can we use this login field to enter an email id or username and authenticate the user.

This is my django login views

```
class LoginForm(generic.CreateView):
print("login")
form_class = LoginForm
template_name = "feed/SignUp.html"

def get(self, request):
    form = self.form_class(None)
    return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

def post(self, request):
    form = self.form_class(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        UserModel = get_user_model()
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']

        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('')
    else:
        print(form.errors)
```

My idea is same as like we can log in to GitHub account either by username or by email. What should I do to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You could check if the username input is an email with:

```py
from django.core.validators import validate_email

try:
    validate_email(username_field) # If it's a valid email
    username = User.objects.get(email=username_field).username # Get username with email
    authenticate(username=username, password=password_field) # Authenticate that user
except:
    # It's a username, so do the normal authentication
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have to extend the User model and add email as the field. Further you have to update the Manager to get your job done.

following snippet is just for your reference.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager, PermissionsMixin

class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    """
    Override auth.models.UserManager by extending BaseUserManager.
    We changed _create_user method to take email as username.
    """
    use_in_migrations = True

    def _create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The given email must be set')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email=None, password=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')
        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)


class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    """
        Override Django default User model class by extending AbstractBaseUser.
    """
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), blank=False, unique=True, error_messages={ 'unique': _("A user with that email already exists."),})
    is_active = models.BooleanField(_('active'), default=True)

    objects = UserManager()

    EMAIL_FIELD = 'email'
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('user')
        verbose_name_plural = _('users')

    def clean(self):
        super(User, self).clean()
        self.email = self.__class__.objects.normalize_email(self.email)


    def encode_uid(self):
        return urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(self.pk))
```

You may have to override get_user_name and other methods from AbstractBaseUser.

Answer (score 0):

Using Django's built-in User model, we'd have to create a class that handles authentication through email or username by overriding the `authenticate` method of `ModelBackend` [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/backends.py#L40),  and adding your custom backend path to `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` in `settings.py`.

```
# project/app/backends.py

from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

class EmailAuthBackend(ModelBackend):
    def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
        if username is None or password is None:
            return
        UserModel = get_user_model()
        try:
            user = UserModel.objects.get(email=username)  # try with email
        except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
            try:
                user = UserModel.objects.get(username=username)  # or username
            except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
                UserModel().set_password(password)
        else:
            if user.check_password(password) and self.user_can_authenticate(user):
                return user
```

```
# project/settings.py

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',  # default
    'app.backends.EmailAuthBackend',  # custom
]

# remember to override the login redirect url or it defaults to accounts/profile/
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
```

Documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/#authentication-backends

By doing it this way you still have access to the `get_user` and remaining methods from the parent class and do not need to re-implement them.